# Add attachment file option inside the textbox in Angular

Tags: html, angular7

I am trying to add attachment file icon inside the text box.

```html
<div class=row>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Type Here.." >
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="image-upload" id="">
      <label for="file-input">
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/53/53582.svg"/  width="35" height="35">
      </label>
      <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

in the above code right now the attach or upload file option is showing after the text box, but I want this icon to show in the text box (for eg: whtsapp textbox or skype text box).

Can anyone guide me in this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.attachmentWrap {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 250px;
}
.attachmentWrap img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
.attachmentWrap input {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class=row>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="attachmentWrap">
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Type Here.." >
      <label for="file-input">
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/53/53582.svg" alt="" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="image-upload" id="">
      <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I want to add file also by clicking on that icon, but right now it is now able to upload any files.

Comment: I just update the above code snippet now you will add file by clicking on that icon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works! Manage margin-left in % acc to browser screen.

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div class=row>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <img _ngcontent-c68="" height="20" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/53/53582.svg" width="20" style="margin-left: 30%;z-index: 999999;position: absolute;">
    <input  type="text" id="icon" name="firstname" placeholder="Type Here.." >
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="image-upload" id="">
      <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```